# Update database on remote server when a facebook comment is made

Tags: php, python, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I want to update a no_comments row in a database exactly when a facebook comment on my site is made. I would like to do the same thing for likes as well.

I can imagine setting up a cron job that uses the graph API to periodically retrieve the number of comments and likes and update the database but for a large number of objects that are associated with comments the lag introduced is undesirable.

I am not looking for someone to "code a solution" for me...rather can someone point me in the right direction: is it possible to use AJAX to somehow update the database at the point when a comment is made or a like is done?

I can see how one can use the click event for the like button but it's not fool proof...

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Oauth and have a facebook application then I would consult the facebook API docs for events or triggers.  If a method exists it will be in the API docs.

Your description of your "site" is vague so it is hard to understand what your site or how it connects to facebook.

**Edit:**
I wish people would explain down votes.  I can't fix it if I don't know what the issue was.

I followed my own advice and searched for this "facebook run script when like is clicked" on Google and found this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125631/how-to-execute-script-after-a-user-clicks-like-on-a-facebook-like-button)  This is almost the same question except it deals with "like" buttons rather than comments.

You can generate "events" like I had previously suggested.  So further consultation of the FB API may be the most fruitful way of finding out if there are events around "comments" as well as "likes".

Maybe the OP knows this, but there are several APIs (last time I checked) to facebook including Javascript methods that could be used in an Ajax manner.  However, without further details of their website implementation there is no way to tell.